# Selenium/Java No Such Element Exception for elements of a page after following a link from homepage

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

New to automation and could use some help here.

I am using Selenium Webdriver and Java on this website - [Webdriver University](http://webdriveruniversity.com/) and so far this code has been throwing No Such Element exception at "element.click()" step (i.e., doesn't find the element on page):

```
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://webdriveruniversity.com");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
// Follow the link to another page
        WebElement link = driver.findElementByXPath("(//div[@class=\"section-title\"])[6]");
        link.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
// Click on the element
        WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("(//button[@class='accordion'])[1]");
        element.click();
```

However, when I go to the linked page directly, it finds the element just fine

```
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://webdriveruniversity.com/Accordion/index.html");

// Click on the element
    WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("(//button[@class='accordion'])[1]");
        element.click();
```

I've used wait for element visibility and Thread sleeps, same results.
Any idea what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice that when you click the link, page is opened in new tab? That is your issue.
You need to switch to new tab.

```java
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //here you are switch to second tab
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope the below code will solve your issues.**

```
Used the getWindowHandles() to capture handle of newly opened tab and switch to the 
tab

// Follow the link to another page
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"section-title\"][6]"));
link.click();
Set<String> allWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> itr = allWindow.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
String wind = itr.next().toString();
driver.switchTo().window(wind);
}
Thread.sleep(3000);

// Click on the element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='accordion'][1]"));
element.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.close();
}
```

Comment: @Gaj's answer helped and is much simpler. Thank you for trying, though.

Comment: @katarinen can you give the points to the answer if it helps you